# Substitute for case statement in Python checking for one of three substrings in a string

Tags: python, switch-statement

Consider the following string:

payments = 'cash:yes,square_cash:no,venmo:no'

If "cash:yes" is found in the string, I would like to return "cash." If "square_cash:yes" is found in the string, I'd like to return "Square Cash" and so on.

I think I'm close, but can't quite figure it out. Here's my code:

```
payments = 'cash:yes,square_cash:no,venmo:no'

def get_payment_type(x):
    return {
        x.find('cash:yes') !=-1: 'Cash',
        x.find('square_cash:yes') !=-1: 'Square Cash',
        x.find('venmo:yes') !=-1: 'Venmo'
    }.get(x, 'not found')    # default if x not found

return {'payment_used': get_payment_type(payments) }
```

This always returns "not found", so I know my syntax is off, just not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific error here is reversing the dictionary keys and values.

`dict.get` looks up a key and the key is first in the dict syntax:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

So if you reverse the keys and values in your answer, it could work.

However, I would recommend a number of changes:

1. Use if/else and return instead of trying to be clever with dicts. Much easier to read
2. use `x in y` instead of `y.find(x) != -1`
3. instead of matching strings, a more robust, nicer and more general method is parsing the string into a dictionary.

Here is an example using if, else instead:

```
if "square_cash:yes" in payments:
    return "square_cash"
elif "cash:yes" in payments:
    return "Cash"
elif "venmo:yes" in payments:
    return "Venmo"
else:
    return "not found"
```

Here is a quick sketch of how parsing this into a dictionary could look:

```
result = {}
for element in payments.split(","):
    key, value = element.split(":")
    result[key] = value
```

Comment: all of this is true & good advice, but this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: You spoke to soon. I guess someone in this question is angry about being downvoted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I will add a version of OPs code that works

Comment: @Azsgy actually, the upvote was cancelled. Noone is currently downvoting your answer. And this "why (not) the downvote ?" running gag is fun.

Comment: I do think that "reverse the key, value pairs" does answer the question

Comment: TBH the question is really too confusing in the first place.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited to include a more concrete solution

Comment: This contains the same bug as one of the other answers: `"cash:yes" in payments` is also true whenever `"square_cash:yes" in payments` is true.

Comment: Yes, true. Let me fix that.

Comment: Thank you, @Azsgy. I went with your first two suggestions on the if/then and x in y.

Answer (score 1):

To handle arbitrary input, use regex to capture the desired payment type and then if the type exists in the full payment string, capitalize the parts found by `re.findall`:

```
import re
payment_types = {'cash:yes,square_cash:no,venmo:no':"cash:yes", 'cash:yes,square_cash:yes,venmo:no':"square_cash:yes"}
final_type = {a:' '.join(i.capitalize() for i in re.findall('^[a-zA-Z_]+(?=:)', b)[0].split('_')) if b in a else None for a, b in payment_types.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'cash:yes,square_cash:yes,venmo:no': 'Square Cash', 'cash:yes,square_cash:no,venmo:no': 'Cash'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by comma and then use you can use `in` to check if string is list.

**Ex:**

```
payments = 'cash:no,square_cash:yes,venmo:no'.split(",")
if "cash:yes" in payments:
    print('Cash')
elif "square_cash:yes" in payments:
    print("square_cash")
elif "venmo:yes" in payments:
    print("Venmo")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: probably because it doesn't work. The first condition catches the second condition. When you're answering such basic things you have to make it right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. sorry i do not understand?

Comment: @Rakesh, the first condition, i.e, `if "cash:yes" in payments` will also cover the second condition, i.e, `if "square_cash:yes" in payments`.

Comment: If `"square_cash:yes" in payments` is true, then `"cash:yes" in payments` will also be true. So you never reach the second condition. Although, admittedly, this bug was also in OP's original code.

Comment: Oh good catch; didn't realize "cash:yes" was repeated. Oops and thanks!

Comment: Thanks Raghav and Pig12. Now i understand

Comment: Updated snippet.